# Get input to [[String]] Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, input

I want to get my input to be a list of lists.
Each row of text has to be a list of strings and the full text will be the list of lists. How could I do this? 
I have this as the main:

```
main :: IO ()
main = interact (lines >>> foo >>> unlines)
```

So if this is the input:

```
These are random
Words of text
example example example
```

The result should be this:

```
[[These, are, random], [Words, of, text],[example, example, example]]
```

Comment: It is not really clear how you would convert the `[String]` list into a `[[String]]` list. Based on what condition? Do you want the "words" of that line?

Comment: I have added an example

Answer (score 1):

Haskell has a function `words :: String -> [String]`. For example:

```
Prelude> words "These are random"
["These","are","random"]
```

Now we can do this for a list of lines by using `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`:

```
Prelude> map words ["These are random","Words of text","example example example"]
[["These","are","random"],["Words","of","text"],["example","example","example"]]
```

You can combine this with `lines` to extract the lines of the string first:

```
Prelude> (map words . lines) "These are random\nWords of text\nexample example example"
[["These","are","random"],["Words","of","text"],["example","example","example"]]
```

So if `foo` has type `foo :: [[String]] -> [[String]]`, you can use:

```
main = interact (unlines . map unwords . foo . map words . lines)
```